# Declare array and set values inside a switch

Tags: php, arrays, switch-statement

I have an error on a switch with array.
This is my code:

```
    $categorie = [];

    switch ($this->categoria) {
        case "S":
            $categorie = array("S");
            break;
        case "C":
            $categorie = array("C", "S");
            break;
        case "J":
            $categorie = array("J", "C", "S");
            break;
        case "R":
            $categorie = array("R", "J", "C", "S");
            break;
        case "EA":
            $categorie = array("EA", "R", "J", "C", "S");
            break;
        case "EB":
            $categorie = array("EB", "EA", "R", "J", "C", "S");
            break;
        default:
            $categorie = [];
    }
```

I have error on Sentry. This is the error: Notice: Undefined variable: categorie

The value of $this->categoria is always set on my tests; here a debug values of sentry:

```
{
  categoria: R
}
```

Comment: I can't see any mistakes in these lines of code, except maybe your first line `$categorie = [];` being unnecessary. That wouldn't trow an error though.

Comment: `$this` implies you are OOP, are you sure about the scope with the error message and your `$categorie` usage?

Comment: yes, I'm using OOP, I think to use it correctly.
Thanks for your suggestion @DirkJ.Faber, I will remove the first row.
The problem is not resolved :(

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% on this, but I believe your issue is comes from not using implode. You are comparing an array of characters to strings with each of your cases for the switch statement. What you might need to do is combine your array into a string for the switch statement when you are comparing each case, like so:

```
$categoria = [];
$a = implode("",$categoria);
switch ($a) {
    case "S":
        $categoria = array("S");
        break;
    case "C":
        $categoria = array("C", "S");
        break;
    case "J":
        $categoria = array("J", "C", "S");
        break;
    case "R":
        $categoria = array("R", "J", "C", "S");
        break;
    case "EA":
        $categoria = array("EA", "R", "J", "C", "S");
        break;
    case "EB":
        $categoria = array("EB", "EA", "R", "J", "C", "S");
        break;
    default:
        $categoria = [];
}
```

*Also, depending on the compiler you use, you might get an error when using $this for $categoria since it is not a static array.

Comment: Hi @tyler-mc thanks for your answer but $categorie is different from $this->categoria, so your solution is not applicable.

Answer (score -2):

I run the your code. There is no problem. Just I changed this line;

```
 switch ($this->categoria) {
```

to

```
switch ("S") {
```

Are you using the **categorie** variable elsewhere on the page?

Comment: `$this->categoria` != `categorie`. There is no problem with the code.

Comment: I mean, I didn't have that variable, so I gave it a value and it worked. there is no problem.